# What crash does FAA SAIB CE-10-11 refer to?

Tags: safety, circuit-breaker

The Federal Aviation Administration released [Special Airworthiness Information Bulletin CE-10-11](https://www.faasafety.gov/files/notices/2009/Dec/SAIB_CE-10-11.pdf) on December 23, 2009 advising pilots of what procedures to use when resetting tripped circuit breakers. The background section refers to a crash where the airplane's weather radar system wiring caused a burning smell and the pilot pulled the breaker. When the breaker was reset for the next flight that flight subsequently crashed. I'm curious what flight this bulletin refers to because I'd like to read its associated NTSB report.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It was NTSB accident ID NYC07MA162. A Cessna 310R went down in Florida in 2007, the NTSB information is [here](http://www.ntsb.gov/investigations/AccidentReports/Pages/AAR0901.aspx) and the flight was [analyzed by AOPA](http://www.aopa.org/News-and-Video/All-News/2009/May/1/Safety-Pilot-Somethings-burning?_ga=1.105992899.1753081362.1440529514). The NTSB [report](http://www.ntsb.gov/investigations/AccidentReports/Reports/AAR0901.pdf) has lots of details, the aircraft was owned and operated by [NASCAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NASCAR), who [unsuccessfully sued Cessna](http://www.sportingnews.com/nascar-news/2055363-judge-tosses-out-nascar-lawsuit-against-cessna-over-deadly-2007-plane-crash) after the accident.

Answer (score 9):

From the details it sounds like the accident was N501N, a Cessna 310R that crashed on 10 July 2007 ([NTSB Summary Report (PDF)](http://www.ntsb.gov/investigations/AccidentReports/Reports/AAR0901.pdf)).  This airplane had been previously written up for an anomaly with the weather radar and subsequently improperly released back into service.  The accident crew reported smoke in the cockpit and post-crash analysis revealed substantial electrical component damage, burned wire insulation, etc.